# What is the difference between "is" and "=="?

Tags: python, equality

What is the difference between these two pieces of code in the boolean world:

```
1 is 1
```

and

```
1 == 1
```

I found two web pages that describe it, but I can't see the difference since I don't know how to get different results:

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=459269&seqNum=10

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

On the 2nd page, I found the operators. On the 1st page, which I looked at second, it described a difference that doesn't tell me when I'd do this and get different results. That's my big question, is when does doing one differ results from the other?

Obviously, there are cases where one will be true and the other false, right?

Comment: I notice I get different results when comparing integers to floats, but when else would it matter about the object type?

Answer (score 1):

When using variables, it can cause incorrect results:

```
>>> foo = [1, 2, 3]
>>> foo is [1, 2, 3]
False
>>> foo == [1, 2, 3]
True
```

Look at the documentation, [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons)

`==` means "equal", while `is` is an object identity.

Answer (score 1):

Equality is well-defined, type by type, depending only on the values being compared.  **Identity** depends on whether a certain value is duplicated, or stored only once and referred to repeatedly.

For immutable values, identity's therefore an implementation detail!

Consider, for example:

```
2>>> x = 23
2>>> y = 23
2>>> x is y
True
2>>> x = 232323
2>>> y = 232323
2>>> x is y
False
```

Small values like `23` happen to be "cached" (an implementation detail!) in CPython in the hope of saving memory if they're used often; large values like `232323` are **not** so cached -- again, 100% an implementation detail.  You'd never want to **depend** on such behavior!

Comment: Wow. I did not know small integers being interned was a CPython feature as well.

Comment: @AnirudhRamanathan, it currently is, it might not be in CPython 3.X for some X -- that's the very definition of an **implementation detail** one should never depend on!-)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to these, you can change the behavior of `==` for classes that you define.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __eq__(self, other):
        #let us ignore b in our comparison!
        return self.a == other.a

a1 = A(1,2)
a2 = A(1,3)
print(a1 == a2) #prints true
print(a1 is a2) #prints false
```

The behavior of `is` cannot be changed and **will** always compare the memory addresses where the objects themselves are stored.

Answer (score 0):

a is b checks if a points to the same memory location as b
a == b checks if the values of a and b are the same.
e.g.

```
a=10 (computer stores '10' at 0xf34852)
b=10 (computer stores '10' at 0xfeac54)
a==b (true)
a is b (false)
```